# Getting some errors that I don't know how to fix in this method

Tags: java, methods, runtime-error

What am I doing wrong here? I'm getting errors on `getMenuChoice()` method where I'm trying to set my users choice = footballTeam1 and footballTeam2 depending on what letter they enter. In the method I'm supposed to print the menu of options to the user, and accept the users choice using scanner keyboard. If then the user does not choose a listed option reprint the menu and ask again, I'm supposed to return the user's choice as a String. Here is my code.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class FootballGame { 
static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
static int arewedone = 0;
static String choice;




public static void main(String[] args) {
      FootballTeam footballTeam1;
      FootballTeam footballTeam2;



    System.out.print("Enter a name for a team:");
    footballTeam1 = new FootballTeam(keyboard.nextLine(), 0);
    System.out.print("Enter a name for another team:");
    footballTeam2 = new FootballTeam(keyboard.nextLine(), 0);

do{
    System.out.println("Game Score:");
    System.out.println(footballTeam1.getName() + ":" + footballTeam1.getScore());
    System.out.println(footballTeam2.getName() + ":" + footballTeam2.getScore());

    choice = getMenuChoice();
    score = handleTeamScore(FootballTeam team);
}while(arewedone == 0);
}

public static String getMenuChoice(FootballTeam footballTeam1, FootballTeam footballTeam2) {
    String input;




    do {
        System.out.println("Select an option:");
        System.out.println("A:" + footballTeam1 + " scored");
        System.out.println("B:" + footballTeam2 + " scored");
        System.out.println("C: game ended.");
        System.out.println("?:");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
            choice = (footballTeam1);
            arewedone = 0;
        } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
            choice = (footballTeam2);
            arewedone = 0;
        } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
            System.out.println("Game Over");
            arewedone++;
        }



    } while (!input.equals("A") && !input.equals("B") && !input.equals("C"));
   return choice;

}
public static void handleTeamScore(FootballTeam team) {

    int points;

    do {

        System.out.println("How many points were scored?");

        System.out.print("?: ");

        points = keyboard.nextInt();

        if ((team.addScore(points)) == true) {

            arewedone++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("That was an invalid option. Please try again.");
            System.out.println("Hints:");
            System.out.println("Touchdown = 6 points");
            System.out.println("Field Goal = 3 points");
            System.out.println("Safety = 2 points");
            System.out.println("Extra Point = 1 point");
                }
        } while (arewedone == 0);

}

}
```

Comment: What are those errors? At first glance I found out that you haven't initialized `input` in your `getMenuChoice`. Please post the errors you are getting, to help you further.

Comment: Yes I have, I've initialized input = keyboard.nextLine();

Comment: I'm getting errors on choice = (footballTeam1); and choce = (footballTeam2);

Comment: What all those errors?

Comment: incompatible types, requires string found FootballTeam

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign object in a string which two are not compatible.
If you really want to do that you have to cast before with object type.

Comment: Could you try and explain? I'm new to all of this haha

Comment: then before try to solve this problem, you must have to study some related feature in java: Object, Class Instantiation, Class Casting.
Please, try to search those keyword in google and study until you don't have a clear concept on those. I hope you will be able to catch your own solution then.